# How can I replace %s to vector using sprintf()?

Tags: r

I want to replace %s as a vector.

So, I coded as below:

```r
items <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
items.txt <- sprintf("y <- c(%s)", items)
```

My expected result is:

```r
"y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")"
```

But real result is:

```r
"y <- c(a)"   "y <- c(b)"   "y <- c(c)"   "y <- c(d)"
```

Thus I tried as follows:

1. `items.txt <- sprintf("y <- c(%s)", paste(items, collapse - ","))`
2. `items.txt <- sprintf("y <- c(%s)", paste(items, collapse - '","'))`

But these are not working.

Are there are any ideas for solving this problem?

Comment: I am a bit confused by the name of your variable, `items.txt`. Are you trying to write out a file?

Comment: Yes. I want to make a source file and open it on the script. The script from Bolker is working. Thanks.

Comment: if one of the answers below solved your problem you are encouraged to click on the check-mark to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems easiest to me:

```r
s <- sprintf("y <- c(%s)", paste(sprintf('"%s"',items), collapse=","))
```

Note that `print(s)` will look weird because of the backslashes protecting the quotation marks. `cat(s,"\n")` looks more normal:

```
y <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

`dput(items, textConnection("s", "w"))` might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```r
items <- 'c("a", "b", "c", "d")'
items.txt <- sprintf('"y <- %s"', items)
cat(items.txt)
# "y <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")"
```